# If I don't know the maximum input in a single line and I'm using split(); how can I use map()?

Tags: python

```
N = int(input())
my_list = list()
for _ in range(N):
    operation, num1, num2 = map(str, input().split())
    if operation == "insert":
        my_list.insert(int(num1), int(num2))
    elif operation == "print":
        print(my_list)
    elif operation == "remove":
        my_list.remove(int(num1))
    elif operation == "append":
        my_list.append(int(num1))
    elif operation == "sort":
        my_list.sort()
    elif operation == "reverse":
        my_list.reverse()
    elif operation == "pop":
        my_list.pop(int(num1))
```

I'm an absolute beginner. Sorry if I'm asking something silly but: This code works when I input 3 variables like "insert 3 4" because they get assigned to operation, num1 and num2 but when I have only "print" input map() doesn't work because it expects 3 variable and I'm only giving 1. How can I work around that because I can't input "print 0 0"

Comment: `str.split()` returns a list of strings. Your map is pointless, as all you're doing is taking an iterable of strings and calling `str()` on them.

Comment: Why don't you just take the user input normally, split it, and then just decide what to do based on how many arguments were passed? You clearly already know how to use `if-elif-else`.

Comment: The line `operation, num1, num2 = map(str, input().split())` doesn't make sense anyway. `input().split()` gives you a list with strings. There's no reason to try to convert a string into a string.

Comment: Also, to be clear, it isn't `map()` that is expecting 3 arguments, it's your tuple unpacking, `operation, num1, num2 = ...` that is expecting exactly 3 items.

Comment: Don't do `operation, num1, num2 = map(str, input().split())` because that presupposes you have 3 data items (operation and 2 numbers) in the input. Instead do `expr =  input().split()`. Then `expr` will be a list, `expr[0]` will be the operation, and `expr[1]`, `expr[2]` etc will be the operands.

Comment: Why would you always want to enforce two number arguments when only one branch of your logic requires two numbers? I suggest doing something like `op, *nums = input().split()`, where the operation must be first, and `nums` will be a list of extra arguments.

Comment: Ohhh...So it's not the map() expecting 3 arguments, it's me forcing 3 arguments. I get it now. Thank you guys so much. @ddejohn

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of that. Instead of forcing 3 items, I'll list what I got and pick them by the index to put them into use. Thanks. @BoarGules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign values manually after mapping, checking first if there is a value.

```
num1,num2 = 0,0
vals = input().split()
vals_str = map(str, vals)
operation = vals_str[0]
if len(val) > 2: num2 = vals_str[2]
elif len(val) > 1: num1 = vals_str[1]
```

You can also check the length of the input array before mapping:

```
vals = input().split()
if len(vals) == 3:
    operation, num1, num2 = map(str, vals)
elif len(vals) == 2: operation, num1 = map(str, vals)
elif len(vals) == 1: operation = str(vals[0])
else: 
    print("Improper input provided")
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of arguments:

```
# Split the input by spaces, store the first
# element in the variable command and
# the remaining in the list args
command, *args = input().split()

if command == "print":
    print(my_list)

elif command == "insert"
    my_list.insert(int(args[0]), int(args[1]))

elif command == "append":
    my_list.append(int(args[0]))
```